# New fuse box installed, tripping!

Tags: electrical

Recently had a new fuse box installed, apparently we had a very old system that wouldn’t pass the safety check.

Had no problem with the old system, but the new one has tripped the sockets/cooker, the lights work ok.

Ive unplugged every plug and I’ve tried flicking the sockets and cooker switches on the board off and trying the tripped switch again and it won’t go back on. Also if I turn the lights off and try the tripped switch that’s meant for the sockets it will go on till I turn a light on and it trips again! Surely this shouldn’t be on the same circuit?

Only had this installed a few days ago, and the electrician can’t come back till tomorrow. Any help?

Comment: Those circuits need replacing - sounds like there is a cross wire somewhere and possibly other faults as well. While you think you had no problem with the old system, perhaps you were close to becoming a statistic...

Comment: It could be a simple skinned wire in the box that is shorting causing the breaker to trip, I have this happen to me and at least 2 apprentices that have worked for me have done the same over the years, and this was with 120v sounds like you could be in 240v land so it could be the problem.

Comment: Are these RCBOs that are tripping, or regular breakers?

Comment: The RCB for the sockets and cooker is tripping

Comment: Did the electrician actually dead test this installation before energising it and carrying out live tests? Have you been given an IET Design Installation and Test certificate (assuming this is the UK)? A new consumer unit installation should not have been left as working with these defects.

Answer (score 1):

### The installer naffed up the neutrals

From your troubleshooting steps so far, this sounds suspiciously like the installer landed a neutral on the wrong neutral bar in the consumer unit.  Since this is a new installation, I would have the installer come back and straighten it out.